# Custom Number Format for CTRL+A

Tags: key-bindings

The `ctrl+A` command to increment numbers is super handy, but it doesn't work in languages that don't use C-style `0x` and `0` prefixes for hexadecimal and octal numbers. In SystemVerilog, hexadecimal numbers are written as `<length_in_bits>'h<hex_number>`. (A capital H will also work). Is there a way to add this number format to Vim so I can increment it with the command?

Comment: Fwiw, tpope did this in his speeddating plugin for dates and times. You might be able to borrow the infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `h` to `0x`, apply  `[count]<c-a>`, then change `0x` back to `h`:

```
nnoremap <expr> <silent> <c-a> expand('<cWORD>') =~# '\v\c\d+''h[0-9a-f]+' ?
      \ ":<c-u>norm! \"_yiWf'ls0x<c-v><esc>" . v:count1 . "<c-v><c-a>F'lvlpE<cr>" : '<c-a>'
nnoremap <expr> <silent> <c-x> expand('<cWORD>') =~# '\v\c\d+''h[0-9a-f]+' ?
      \ ":<c-u>norm! \"_yiWf'ls0x<c-v><esc>" . v:count1 . "<c-v><c-x>F'lvlpE<cr>" : '<c-x>'
```

Break down the 1st return value of the ternary operator:

- `:<c-u>norm!` Do a series of commands without screen update in the middle. You screen will flicker without this. `<c-u>` is used to remove `:h N:`.
- `"_yiW` Move cursor to start of current `<WORD>` without copying anything.
- `f'ls0x` find ', cursor right to `h`, change it to 0x
- `<c-v><esc>` escape insert mode. You need `<c-v>` to insert literal `<esc>` in command line.
- `v:count1 . "<c-v><c-a>` let vim increase hex value `:h v:count1` times for you
- `F'lvlp` find `'` backward, replace `0x` with original h or H in default register.
- `E` back to end of hex value, to be consistent with vim.