# Ctrl-A/Ctrl-X for numbers with a decimal number

Tags: key-bindings

I have numbers

```
0.655
1.455
1.21
```

How do I increment/decrement these numbers by their thousandths digit such that `901<c-a>` produces:

```
1.556
2.356
2.111
```

I saw this question, which may be applicable here:

[Custom Number Format for CTRL+A](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/custom-number-format-for-ctrla)

Comment: Doing it manually is slightly less intutitive but put the cursor to the right of the decimal and `901CTRL-A` increments the decimal. I often want to increment to the left of the decimal and to the right separately for testing

Comment: @Steve But e.g. 0.655 will not become 1.556, because the native <c-a> behavior does not consider anything to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: Ah yeah missed that bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something similar recently, I changed it again to make `<c-a>` and `<c-x>` work on any step.

You may get the command [here](https://github.com/dedowsdi/.vim/blob/cd6b90fdb29a49c4ffd8b04bc90049015773ee8e/plugin/misc.vim#L247) and the function [here](https://github.com/dedowsdi/.vim/blob/cd6b90fdb29a49c4ffd8b04bc90049015773ee8e/autoload/misc.vim#L637).

It support `123.24` or `123.` or `123` or `.123` style number, `count` is also supported now:

```
# change slide step to 0.000001, 
Slide 0.000001

# change slide step to 0.1, save after slide. I use this to
# trigger some hot reload.
Slide! 0.1

# retrieve default behavior
Slide 1
```

Comment: Note that nunmap will fail if the mapping doesn’t exist

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks, updated.

Comment: Seems :execute "Slide 0.001" and <c-a> work, but e.g. 2<c-a> doesn't work on e.g. 1.3334

Comment: @Ralph See update.

Comment: Hmm, still seems to not work (I guess for now I will wrap <c-a> in a register and use @ to call it). Thanks again for your answer, btw. I am a novice/intermediate vim user, but was inspired by your answer to read up to ch23 [here](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html)

Comment: @Ralph It should work, I just tried it. You need to call `:source %` on script file if you don't want to restart vim. You can do all kinds of customization after learning `vimscript` :) .

Comment: Now it works. I also had to change misc# to s:

Comment: @dedowsdi Why not add the function and function call into your answer? It would be really great too if you could explain a few nuances here and there such as misc# vs. s: so that newbies like myself can learn vimscript quicker and with less pain. Of course, we can google hunt for random syntax, but it takes us 2x as much time.